# Having trouble calling a method from inside another method

Tags: c#, methods

I'm still a beginner in C# but while working with methods, I learned that I could call a method from inside a method. However, I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

```
namespace Methods
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("I'm about to go into a method.");
            CountToTen();
            //Console.WriteLine("I am no longer in a method.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void CountToTen()
        {
            for (int index = 1; index <= 10; index++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(index);
            }
            RandomMessage();
        }

        static string RandomMessage()
        {
            return "Test";
        }
    }
}
```

My logic for this is that the program will go into the Main method, perform what's in the CountToTen method, do the for loop, continue through that method into the RandomMessage method, return "Test", then exit back to the `Console.ReadKey();` line. However, it only does the for loop then stops. Any ideas?

Comment: Well it does return "Test" but you ignore the return value. It's not really clear what you think is wrong.

Comment: How do you say it doesn't execute `RandomMessage`? Put a `Console.Write` inside it, It will be executed

Comment: I actually thought that just by putting `return "Test";` it would write it on the screen. Didn't occur to me (strangely) to use `Console.Write` or `Console.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.Writeline(RandomMessage());
```

Thats what you're looking for :)
because it will return a string but you didn't do anything with it yet so just print it out like above or store it in a variable.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, thank you! I thought that just by putting a return statement it would write to the console, sorta like Python.

Answer (score 1):

Try to actually do something with the return value of `RandomMessage`
Right now you just call the method.